# get every result of a query to use after

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to get every result of a query to then print an output and make other query with the result. I'm trying to make it with a Cursor. But when I try to print the query result it says me:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'
```

My code is:

```
DECLARE
-- Store the SELECT query in a cursor
  CURSOR l_cur IS select memname from emuser.DEF_TABLES@controlm t, emuser.DEF_JOB@controlm j where (t.TABLE_ID = j.TABLE_ID) and t.sched_table = 'DWHRAC_DIARIOS2_DC2'; 
--Create a variable that will hold each result from the cursor
  l_cur_rec l_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Open the Cursor so that we may retrieve results
  OPEN l_cur;  
  LOOP
    -- Get a result from the SELECT query and store it in the variable
    FETCH l_cur INTO l_cur_rec;
    -- EXIT the loop if there are no more results
    EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;
    -- INSERT INTO another table that has the same structure as your results
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_cur_rec);

  END LOOP;
  -- Close the cursor to release the memory
  CLOSE l_cur;
END;
```

Could you help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` accepts a single string as a parameter, but here it is being passed a variable of type `l_cur%ROWTYPE` which is not allowed. You should change the call to `PUT_LINE` to specify the name of the column(s) you want to print, such as:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cur_rec.MEMNAME);
```

Share and enjoy.